# Association Error with Sorcery Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rubygems, sorcery

I used Sorcery to set up authentication in Rails and I'm trying to create a model where the user id for the user is linked as reference to the model for data entered, but I get an error:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

it refers to the following code:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @certificate = @user.certificates.create(certificate_params)
  redirect_to certificate_path(@certificate)
end
```

To answer basic questions I've asked myself, the user is logged in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a very weird error if the above is really your code. You should have gotten something like `Couldn't find Bar with 'id'=` instead. The error above is usually only given if you provide no args to `find` at all, ie. `User.find()`

Anyway, the underlying problem here is that `params[:user_id]` doesn't contain the value you expect it to, and probably it contains no value at all. You haven't shown enough of your other code to determine why that is, **BUT** it doesn't matter...

Unless you want people to be able to just change the URL and add a certificate for some other user in your system then you shouldn't rely on the `params[:user_id]` for creating associated objects, you should use `current_user` - that's kind of the whole point of authentication.

So:

```
def create
  @certificate = current_user.certificates.create(certificate_params)
  redirect_to certificate_path(@certificate)
end
```